# Determine Capacity for Airline Membership Model

Tags: economics

I am trying to determine a simple calculation for capacity for one single 747 plane -- there are 200 seats on the plane and the plane flies twice per day, every day of the year.

If there was a membership model where each person had a an allotment of 4 round trips per month, how many total members could one plane support?

I am currently thinking of the issue like this-200 seats x 2 flights per day x 365 is 146,000 seats.  If each member gets 8 seats per month, then max total number of members would be 146,000 ÷ (12*8) which is 1,520.